# How to remove words without vowels from a list in python

Tags: python

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
my_list = ['hbyl','hawk','ibzj','hcxk','gawk']
```

for word in my_list. If word does not have one vowel. Delete word from list

```
for word in my_list:
    if word does not include at least one vowel:
        my_list.remove(word)

print (my_list)
['hawk','ibzj','gawk']
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work! :)

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u'] 
my_list = ['hbyl','hawk','ibzj','hcxk','gawk']
vowset = set(vowel)
[word for word in my_list if vowset.intersection(word)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove elements while iterating. Instead, construct a new list, preferably with a list comprehension:

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
my_list = ['hbyl','hawk','ibzj','hcxk','gawk']

new_my_list = [word for word in my_list if any(v in word for v in vowel)]
```

Essentially, what the list comprehension says is "include any given word only if there are any vowels in this word."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `filterfalse()` with the set method `isdisjoint()`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
my_list = ['hbyl','hawk','ibzj','hcxk','gawk']

vowel= set(vowel)
list(filterfalse(lambda x: vowel.isdisjoint(x), my_list))
# ['hawk', 'ibzj', 'gawk']
```